# vs-code: Commands not found after switch to ubuntu as terminal

Tags: python, c, ubuntu, visual-studio-code, terminal

So I switched from powershell to ubuntu as my terminal for vs-code but I always get this error when ever I'm compiling a C or a python program I get the following errors:

```
cd "C:\Users\boula\AppData\Local\Temp\" && gcc tempCodeRunnerFile.c -o tempCodeRunnerFile && "C:\Users\boula\AppData\Local\Temp\"tempCodeRunnerFile
-bash: cd: C:\Users\boula\AppData\Local\Temp" && gcc tempCodeRunnerFile.c
-o tempCodeRunnerFile && C:UsersboulaAppDataLocalTemp"tempCodeRunnerFile:
No such file or directory
for c
and python -u "C:\Users\boula\AppData\Local\Temp\tempCodeRunnerFile.python"

Command 'python' not found, did you mean:

  command 'python3' from deb python3
  command 'python' from deb python-is-python3
```

in python.

BTW both `gcc` and `python3` are installed correctly in that linux ubuntu ternminal.

Comment: Powershell is a shell and ubuntu is an operating system, so your question makes no sense.

Comment: I can see in your output that by ubuntu you mean to say `bash`. Notice `C:UsersboulaAppDataLocalTemp` in your output: the back slashes aren't there. Windows uses back slashes but bash uses forward slashes for file separators which is at least part of the issue there. You need to add python to your path in bash for it to know what you mean, although python3 might be what you're using.

Comment: @martineau VS code allows you to use select Ubuntu WSL in the [integrated terminal](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal#_terminal-profiles) I think it just uses bash or zsh... idk i've only seen the button. But that's probably where OP got confused.

Comment: Could you check whether you have installed the python out of the VSCode? And the first command is just in a mess, have you make some configurations in the settings.json?